# Should I obfuscate my plugin before sharing with others?

Tags: jquery, obfuscation

I am learning jQuery and I am writing a jQuery plugin and would be happy to share with others (off-course those who want) when completed. I recently learned that obfuscation would help me with securing the code as well as making it light-weight. But I also found that obfuscated JS is often used to insert malicious code. As I am not intending to have any malicious code in my plugin will it effect in people trusting my code to at least try-out if I obfuscate it?
My main idea to use obfuscation is to disallow any edits to code so that my plugin would keep on working as intended. And I beleive obfuscation would help me in that.

Thanks

Comment: You should have a minified and a non-minified version. I wouldn't bother 'obfuscating' it (e.g. adding random crap that makes it harder to read)

Comment: Obfuscation does not, in any way, prevent people making changes to your code. There are plenty of tools out there (e.g. http://jsbeautifier.org), and Developer Tools built into browsers that go a long way to making obfuscated/ minified code much more readable. Normal practice is to distribute both a raw, and obfuscated/ minified version of your code. People use obfuscated code purely to reduce the size of the download of their codebase.

Comment: Thanks sumurai8 and Matt I think it would be best to distribute both versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general consensus with jQuery plugins is to release two versions. The original, uncompressed code, and then another minified version. Indeed, this is the approach that the authors of the jQuery library themselves have adopted, for example:

**Uncompressed >** http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
**Minified >** http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

You should know the difference between the two terms `minified` and `obfuscated`, but generally:

[**Minification:**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29)

> Minification (also minimisation or minimization), in computer
>   programming languages and especially JavaScript, is the process of
>   removing all unnecessary characters from source code without changing
>   its functionality. These unnecessary characters usually include white
>   space characters, new line characters, comments, and sometimes block
>   delimiters, which are used to add readability to the code but are not
>   required for it to execute.

[**Obfuscation:**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29)

> In software development, obfuscation is the deliberate act of creating
>   obfuscated code, i.e. source or machine code that is difficult for
>   humans to understand. Programmers may deliberately obfuscate code to
>   conceal its purpose (security through obscurity) or its logic, in
>   order to prevent tampering, deter reverse engi neering, or as a puzzle or recreational challenge for someone reading the source code.

So in short, `minification != obfuscation`. The idea of releasing a minified version is to reduce the filesize, and this can often be achieved using a combination of minification and onfuscation.

Comment: Disagree that minification is the best technique. The point of the *other* file (the non-raw) is to reduce the file size of the download. Obfuscation is an additional step to further reduce the file size of the code after minifying it. Transparency is achieved by offering the original/raw file.

Comment: I think I agree with Matt anyway if I would provide raw and obfuscated both then I think the idea of open source is also kept intact.